# MS Access Null Not Working as Query Parameter

Tags: ms-access

I have a form with a subform linked by the field DataType, which displays all the data for that DataType and has been working well for years. 
The DataType can be further filtered by several dropdown fields, the fields are parameters in the underlying query for the sub-form, but if these fields are blank it will return all the data for that DataType, and I have a 'Clear all' button that runs code to make all the filter values null/blank except when all the fields are blank all the data is not being returned. I have narrowed the issue down to one field DataFilterC. For some reason the query is no longer treating the field as null/blank even when it is, it will work if I choose an option for it's drop down, this is the criteria for that field;

```
Like IIf(IsNull([Forms]![Form]![SubForm1].[Form]![DataFilterC]),"*",[Forms]! [Form]![SubForm1].[Form]![ DataFilterC]) Or Is Null
```

The query skips the first IsNull and goes straight to the final Or Is Null what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Deal with possibility of either Null or empty string with:

`IIf([Forms]![Form]![SubForm1].[Form]![DataFilterC] & "" = "", "*", ...`

Comment: It seems to be related to the number of records when it hits x records in the query it stops working +/-X by any number and it is fine. Which is a total mystery.